# How to change the brightness of the phone's home screen in Android?

Tags: android

How can i change the Phone's Home screen Brightness programmatically?? i know the below code to change the Brightness. But how to use it for Home Screen??

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = 0.1f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the following code it can be seen that changing screen brightness is done on a system wide level(it is done using a hardware manager). It does not look like it is possible to do it per application.

See Code Below:

```
IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(
ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));
  if (hardware != null) {
    hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);
```

The above source was taken from https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html

Comment: I tried with this. But getiing the exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.IHardwareService.set Screen Backlight

Comment: if I'm not mistaken that means that function is not availible in the Android API level that you are currently using.

Comment: Is there any way to get the Activity name of the Home Screen of the phone??

Comment: I think it static, according to Eclipse it "android.process.acore"